# possible to overload function in matlab class?

Tags: function, matlab, overloading

Is it possible to overload a function in a Matlab class that you've created?

Like the following:

```
    function [ sigma_nc ] = sustained_interference( N )
       sustained_interference( N, N.center_freq);
    end

    function [ sigma_nc ] = sustained_interference( N, center_freq )
       ...
    end
```

Unfortunately when I try this, I get a redefinition error

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630889/overloading-functions/8631335#8631335

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you create the function using the latter, then you can pass it just a single parameter which will be interpreted as the first. If you want default values, then you can do something like this:

```
function [ sigma_nc ] = sustained_interference( N, center_freq )
   if nargin < 2
       center_freq = N.center_freq;
   end
   ...
end
```

Comment: a-ha, there we go... I needed the nargin to make this work.  Thanks a bunch!  When it allows me to accept your answer, I will.