# Argument passing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parameters, arguments, argument-passing, matlab-deployment

I have a function in matlab of the form fun(a,b,c), wherethe using may or may not give argument 'c' when he calls the function.  I have to use a switch case on 'c' later in that function, and thus need to check whether user called the function  with 2 or 3 arguments?

How to do that?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630889/overloading-functions/8631335#8631335

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by using `nargin`:

```
function fun(a,b,c)

if (nargin < 3)
    c = c_default_value;
end

switch c
```

or using `nargin` and `varargin` (this function definition permits unlimited number of arguments):

```
function fun(a,b,varargin)

if (nargin < 3)
    c = c_default_value;
else
    c = varargin{1};
end

switch c
```